# How to recognize response as JSON?

Tags: html

In my ReactJS, I'm making a fetch to an API, and the JSON body response field is the following:

```
{
"place": <a href=\"http:\/\/place.com\/
               search?q=%23MILKYDOG\" target=\"_blank\">#milkydog<\/a>
               and quickly came up with a little comic about it. You can
               (and should) follow Naomi on twitter <a href=\"http:\/\
               /david.com\/ngun\" target=\"_blank\">@ngun<\/a> "
}
```

And when I try to render it by simply passing the prop down (`fetched`) to rather than recognizing the formatting and escape characters, and rendering accordingly to them.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that React is helping you out by not allowing random HTML to be injected in to your app. You'll need to use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) way of injecting the content. This is made difficult on purpose because React is trying to help you avoid XSS attacks. So you have to do this the "dangerous" way so you think about whether you could do this without injecting raw HTML (it looks like you're getting content from a blog system maybe? Probably a good example of the exception to the rule.)

From the React documentation, you can use something like the following:

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

e.g. in your case

```js
var fetchedFile = {
"body": `<p><img src=\"http:\/\/media.tumblr.com\
               /tumblr_lh6x8d7LBB1qa6gy3.jpg\"\/><a href=\"http:\/\
               /citriccomics.com\/blog\/?p=487\" target=\"_blank\">TO READ
               THE REST CLICK HERE<\/a><br\/>\n\nMilky Dog was inspired by
               something <a href=\"http:\/\/gunadie.com\/naomi\"
               target=\"_blank\">Naomi Gee<\/a> wrote on twitter, I really
               liked the hash tag <a href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/
               search?q=%23MILKYDOG\" target=\"_blank\">#milkydog<\/a>
               and quickly came up with a little comic about it. You can
               (and should) follow Naomi on twitter <a href=\"http:\/\
               /twitter.com\/ngun\" target=\"_blank\">@ngun<\/a> `
};


function createMarkup(html) {
  return {__html: html};
}

class MyThing extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(fetchedFile.body)} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyThing />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Great I will give it a try in a bit. I gave it a run of your snippet, but why doesn't it render the image?

Comment: The JSON string had newlines and spaces in it so the URL is broken. With your real data it should work just fine.

Comment: Just got around to try it, but I'm getting an error and it's not being rendered. Error is `Warning: Unknown prop 'dangerouslySetInnerHtml' on <div> tag. Remove this prop from the element.` Ultimately, I'd like to use it inside for `http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card`, inside the `<CardText></CardText>` for Card components example. Would there be a way? Currently it is displaying exactly how it is, when I did `<CardText>{fetchFile.body}</CardText>`. Please let me know so I can accept answer as well with upvote.

Comment: Not at a computer right now, so can't verify, but might be worth trying to use the exact casing FB use in the example. (i.e. dangerouslySetInnerHTML) I'm not sure if that's the issue, but worth giving a quick try.

Comment: Actually got it to work! But the `<img>` are sticking out of the `<Card/>`. How can I get it to be contained inside the `<Card/>`?

Comment: That's likely to be a CSS related question, if you've tried a few things like making the image smaller, making the card bigger, setting `overflow: hidden` on the card, and maybe some other things, and are *still* stuck, make a new SO question for that issue to avoid this one covering too much scope.

Answer (score 0):

React by default always renders as textNode for javascript variables for security reasons, unless you mention it explicitly.

```
render() {
    return(
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHtml={{__html: fetchedFile.body}} />
    )
}
```

Read more on this [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: Just get it a try but got an error is `Warning: Unknown prop 'dangerouslySetInnerHtml' on <div> tag. Remove this prop from the element.` I'd like to use it for `http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card`, inside the `<CardText></CardText>` for Card components example. Would there be a way? Currently it is displaying exactly how it is, when I did `<CardText>{fetchFile.body}</CardText>`.

Comment: @JoKo `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` is React's way of telling the DOM element to set the content passed as `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`. So, that can accept and render custom HTML elements / markup. In this scenario, you'll have to use `<CardText><div dangerouslySetInnerHtml={{__html: fetchedFile.body}} /></CardText>`

Comment: I actually gave that a try but now nothing is showing up at all, even the `<Card/>` http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card

Comment: @JoKo From the documentation ( http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card#card-properties ), the `children` prop is an `HTML node`, where you can pass your HTML I think.

Comment: sorry but could you show to clarify? So I can accept the answer as well.

Comment: Actually got it to work! But the `<img>` are sticking out of the `<Card/>`. How can I get it to be contained inside the `<Card/>`?

Comment: I think it should be `<CardText children={fetchedFile.body} />`. Didn't properly understand the part of `<img>` sticking out of `<Card />`.